# An compile error in VBA after requiring variable declaration

Tags: excel, vba

I have turned on the "require variable declare" option to force to declare the variable in the VBA setting. After recording a Macro, the following recorded Macro fails to run with an error message:

compile error: expected function or variable.

I have tried to turned off the "require variable declare" in tools->options, then the code runs successfully. How to run it when the option is on?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:E4").Select
    selection.Copy
    Range("A16").Select
    activesheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is case sensitive.  selection.Copy should be Selection.Copy and activesheet.Paste should be ActiveSheet.Paste.  Also, unless there is a need to select the cells, you can simplify your code to:

```
Range("A1:E4").Copy Range("A16")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The code is copied from the recorded Macro. I tried to fix it to CAPITAL letter. After click F5, it returns the same error and fix it to lowercase ''selection"'

Comment: @XianhaoZHU do you by chance have another `Sub` named `selection`?

Comment: Are you using Excel's built-in VBA editor or a 3rd party tool?

Comment: @BigBen - Excellent question!  Another related one would be:  Do you have variables named "selection" and/or "activesheet"?

Comment: @BigBen yes i do and i figure it out now. - -! Thanks